# How to show/hide iOS lock screen controls when playing different audios

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

I'm trying to find a way to be able to show/hide lock screen controls when playing different audios.

I've discovered that I can hide the lock screen controls by 
setting the audio session's category with the option of AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
```

However, the lock screen controls will never come back after that even I reset the session.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

I have been struggling for many days trying to find a solution. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: could you solve this issue? thanks!